# to make auto count for the 1st higest values using DAX query

Tags: dax, amazon-dynamodb-dax, daxstudio

In a table I have values
Name   fruits
----------------
xxx     Apple
yyy     Orange
zzz     Papaya
aaa     Pineapple
bbb     Orange
ccc     Papaya
ddd     Papaya
fff     Apple

I need a measure to count the highest repeated value (which is Papaya it repeats 3 times).
I tried with query
CALCULATE(COUNT(call_data[fruits]),FILTER(call_data,call_data[fruits]="Papaya"))

but I have to give the value every time in filter. if another fruit count goes higher then I have to change the filter name.

so how could I write a query to count the 1st highest value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table looks like this and its name is `call_data`

| Fruits |
| --- |
| Apple |
| Orange |
| Papaya |
| Pineapple |
| Orange |
| Papaya |
| Papaya |
| Apple |

You can use the following calculation. The logic is to replicate the table with fruits and the count of each of them and get the max for the count. In this case `3` for `Papaya`

## DAX Calculation:

```
CountMaxFruits =
VAR FruitsTable =
    SUMMARIZE (
        call_data,
        call_data[Fruits],
        "@Count", COUNT ( call_data[Fruits] )
    )
VAR MaxFruits =
    MAXX ( FruitsTable, [@Count] )
RETURN
    MaxFruits
```

## Output

[image]